# Error when trying to put Action Button (using Json method)

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have index.html and ajax.php with detail code in below

**index.html**

> 

```
    <div >
        <!-- Table -->
        <table id='empTable' class='display dataTable'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Script -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#empTable').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'serverMethod': 'post',
            'ajax': {
                'url':'ajaxfile.php'
            },
            'columns': [
                { data: 'emp_name' },
                { data: 'email' },
                { data: 'gender' },
                { data: 'salary' },
                { data: 'city' },
                { data: 'action' },
            ]
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

**ajaxfile.php**

```
$empQuery = "select * from employee WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery." order by ".$columnName." ".$columnSortOrder." limit ".$row.",".$rowperpage;
$empRecords = mysqli_query($con, $empQuery);
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
    $data[] = array(
            "emp_name"=>$row['emp_name'],
            "email"=>$row['email'],
            "gender"=>$row['gender'],
            "salary"=>$row['salary'],
            "city"=>$row['city'],
            "action"=><a  class='btn btn-xs btn-warning' href='user_edit.php?uid='".$row['id']."'; '>
                                    <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Ubah Data
                                </a>

        );
}

## Response
$response = array(
    "draw" => intval($draw),
    "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
    "aaData" => $data
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

then im trying to put action button "user_edit" using my usual method but not working. However if me put action"=>row['id']; the code is working fine. My question is how to put action button with value from row['id']; . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one, your action should be an String. Inside the class you can add something like delete-button. And remove the href or remove the link and just add a number sign like href="#", since you are working with ajax. We dont want to go to other page.

```
$data[] = array(
        "emp_name"=>$row['emp_name'],
        "email"=>$row['email'],
        "gender"=>$row['gender'],
        "salary"=>$row['salary'],
        "city"=>$row['city'],
        "action"=>"<a  class='btn btn-xs btn-warning delete-button' 
        uid='".$row['id']."'; '><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Ubah Data</a>"
    );
```

and then in yout html file or js file, you can create an event for that specific button that has a class of delete-button.

```
$('.delete-button').on('click',function(){
      //get the id by
      var = $(this).attr('uid');
      //functions here
      $.post('http://ajaxfile.php').then(function(res){
            //reload the datatables
            $('#empTable').DataTable.draw();
       });
 });
```

for more details explanation you can watch this videos.
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=jquery+datatables+server-side+processing+

Comment: let me try , thanks for let me know detail explanation.

Comment: Its work man. I modified abit your code . The reason i put href at there is to redirect to Edit Form when execute code at there.  Still i will considering the delete button using your method too later .

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

write action in variable and assign that variable to array action

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
    $action = "<a  class='btn btn-xs btn-warning' href='user_edit.php?uid='".$row['id']."'; '>
                <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Ubah Data
               </a>";
    $data[] = array(
        "emp_name"=>$row['emp_name'],
        "email"=>$row['email'],
        "gender"=>$row['gender'],
        "salary"=>$row['salary'],
        "city"=>$row['city'],
        "action"=>$action;
    );
}
```